# Getting Authentication Error when initializing Firestore Admin SDK on Node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a server with node js that handles data from a client and uploads it to Firestore. I'm still new. This is the code for my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

let app = express();

let upload = multer();

let serviceAccount = require('./psylocke-774e2adbf0e5.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credentials: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
}); 

let db = admin.firestore();

let port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.route('/interface').get((_, res) => {
    try {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/interface.html');
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send(e.message);
    }
})

app.post('/upload', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    let test = {
        name:'juan',
        age:15
    };
    db.collection('roots').doc('sampleroot').set(test).then((mess) => {
        console.log("I went through hwere");
        res.send('it worked');
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.send('it didnt work');
        console.log(err);
    });
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

And this is my project JSON file (which I had to download from google cloud platforms):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "psylocke",
  "private_key_id": "<id>",
  "private_key": "<private key>",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-ja1c3@psylocke.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "113260833969613996508",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-ja1c3%40psylocke.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment.
To learn more about authentication and Google APIs, visit:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

It's weird that I'm getting this error since a project id is actually specified in the json doc. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Firestore. On initializeApp there's an option to pass in the projectID that you need to do. Firestore's integration with IAM isn't good enough (yet) to pull from the service account, particularly since service accounts could (and often do) point to other projects so you might not want it to necessarily.

Check this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase for the options you can pass to that initialize call. E.g.:

```
// Initialize default app
// Retrieve your own options values by adding a web app on
// https://console.firebase.google.com
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIza....",                             // Auth / General Use
  appId: "1:27992087142:web:ce....",              // General Use
  projectId: "my-firebase-project",               // General Use
  authDomain: "YOUR_APP.firebaseapp.com",         // Auth with popup/redirect
  databaseURL: "https://YOUR_APP.firebaseio.com", // Realtime Database
  storageBucket: "YOUR_APP.appspot.com",          // Storage
  messagingSenderId: "123456789",                 // Cloud Messaging
  measurementId: "G-12345"                        // Analytics
});
```

Comment: how is this answer got verified? he is refferring to the admin sdk and youre talking about the js client

Comment: Oop, because I had the wrong link. It's virtually the same though, just two items down on the navigation bar. My guess is they managed to find the correct reference from where I landed them... I'll fix the link and code block to match the client.